# UBUNTU How to make terminal looks like?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

Simple, how can I make my terminal looks like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/images/overview.png

On pic, left one, you see how path (user, host, directory) looks like with fore-color. I am interested how to make it.

Comment: Are you asking how to set the color in your prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you're just asking how to set the color of your prompt.  One way to do that is:

```
PS1="\[$(tput setaf 1; tput setb 2)\]\$\[$(tput setaf 9; tput setb 9)\] "
```